# how can i send JSSoundRecorder recorded file to localhost folder (using jquery and php)

Tags: php, jquery

I have downloaded a recorder with editor from https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder . When you click on record we can here what we have recorded.

Now I wish I could place a "save" button somewhere. Clicking this button the recorded file can be stored on my server, currently at my localhost in folder "sounds".

I tried my best but I think I cant do that. So please give me detail description about where to put which function.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code or can download `recordLive.js` and `save_file.php` from http://www.kcubeinfotech.com/download/audio_recording_file.zip and put it save_file.php and recordLive.js in 'js' folder and check it.

you will get new audio file. 
when you click on save button wait for few seconds one alert with file name appears means file saved successfully.
for more contact me on rajeshkakadiya3292@gmail.com
for more information check this url.
http://www.kcubeinfotech.com/pages/php/how-can-i-send-jssoundrecorder-recorded-file-to-localhost-folder-(using-jquery-and-php)/

// use this in your recordLive.js  from line no.52 handleWAV(blob)

```
function.  you will get save button so it will help to save in your server directly.
function handleWAV(blob) {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById('recordingslist');
  if (currentEditedSoundIndex !== -1) {
  $('#recordingslist tr:nth-child(' + (currentEditedSoundIndex + 1) + 
')').remove();
}

var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(currentEditedSoundIndex);
newRow.className = 'soundBite';
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
var downloadAnchor = document.createElement('a');
var downloadAnchor1 = document.createElement('a');
var editButton = document.createElement('button');

audioElement.controls = true;
audioElement.src = url;

downloadAnchor.href = url;
downloadAnchor.download = new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
downloadAnchor.innerHTML = 'Download';
downloadAnchor.className = 'btn btn-primary';

filename= new Date().toISOString() + '.wav';
downloadAnchor1.download =filename;
downloadAnchor1.id ='button_audio';
downloadAnchor1.setAttribute('onclick','getaudiofile("'+url+'")');
//downloadAnchor1.href = url;
downloadAnchor1.innerHTML = 'Save me';
downloadAnchor1.className = 'btn btn-primary';

editButton.onclick = function(e) {
$('.recorder.container').addClass('hide');
$('.editor.container').removeClass('invisible');

currentEditedSoundIndex = $(e.target).closest('tr').index();

var f = new FileReader();
f.onload = function(e) {
    audio_context.decodeAudioData(e.target.result, function(buffer) {
      console.warn(buffer);
      $('#audioLayerControl')[0].handleAudio(buffer);
    }, function(e) {
      console.warn(e);
    });
};
f.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
};
editButton.innerHTML = 'Edit';
editButton.className = 'btn btn-primary';

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
newCell.appendChild(audioElement);
newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(currentEditedSoundIndex);
newRow.className = 'soundBite';
newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
newCell.appendChild(downloadAnchor);
newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(currentEditedSoundIndex);
newRow.className = 'soundBite';
newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
newCell.appendChild(downloadAnchor1);
newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(currentEditedSoundIndex);
newRow.className = 'soundBite';
newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
newCell.appendChild(editButton);

newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
var toggler;
for (var i = 0, l = 8; i < l; i++) {
  toggler = document.createElement('input');
  $(toggler).attr('type', 'checkbox');
  //newCell.appendChild(toggler);  
  //check box after edit button
}
}

window.onload = function init() {
try {
  // webkit shim
  window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext  || window.mozAudioContext;
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL;

audio_context = new AudioContext();
console.log('Audio context set up.');
console.log('navigator.getUserMedia ' + (navigator.getUserMedia ? 'available.' : 'not present!'));
} catch (e) {
  console.warn('No web audio support in this browser!');
}

navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true}, startUserMedia, function(e) {
  console.warn('No live audio inpuenter code heret: ' + e);
});
};
function getaudiofile(blob)
{
  url=blob;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var myBlob = this.response;
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', myBlob); 
 $.ajax({
    url :  "save_file.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data);
      $('#audio_input_name').val(data);
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage["my"]=data;
      //if(data=="")
      alert("File Save Successfully.");
     // $('#audio_name').val(data);
    },    
    error: function() {
      alert("Please try again Some thing is wrong.");
    }
  });
}
};
xhr.send();
}
```

Create new save_file.php and put this code

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
if(isset($_FILES['file']) and !$_FILES['file']['error']){
  $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $fn="newfile";
  $newfile = $fn.''.$date.".wav";

  $fn = "abc" . ".wav";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'audiofile/'. $fn);

  if(rename('audiofile/'.$fn,'audiofile/'.$newfile)){
     //echo sprintf("%s was renamed to %s",$fn,$newfn);
  }
  echo $newfile;
  }
```

you will get new audio file. 
when you click on save button wait for few seconds one alert with file name appears means file saved successfully.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: i try but i cant put code its showing error. so i created link. If possible than you can help with editing code by here from given link. i can put it here some issue with editors.

Comment: What error do you get? You just have to edit your question and copy paste the most interesting parts of your code inside.

Comment: somthing like > content not proper and must contain 4 spaces. I tried best but still giving same error and cant check in which line no. so i posted link there is too many lines and two files. I dont like that you given minus point to my answer. because this solution is 100% working and many coder not reach to this solution because of rating.

Comment: Link only answers **ARE** bad answers, by definition (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)). I'm not saying that your code is wrong or that your link doesn't answer the question. But if your link become unavailable some day, this answer will be useless. In any case, I cannot remove my down vote unless the answer is edited (which is not that complicated...).

Comment: @Max can you revert the minus rating please. I have updated code in comment. Thanks.